# PyQGIS - Converting WKB to String

Tags: pyqgis, well-known-binary

Using PyQGIS, i'd like to print the string representation of a point WKB
(like what PostGIS displays in geometry columns).
For example:

```
p = QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(2, 4))
wkb = p.asWkb()
print toBinString(wkb) # "000000000140000000000000004010000000000000"
print toHexString(wkb) # Would print what PostGIS does
```

Would you know how i could achieve this?

(Example data is taken from [Wikipedia WKT article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text#Well-known_binary))

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `.encode('hex')` method:

```
wkb = b'\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10@'
print(wkb.encode('hex'))  # 010100000000000000000000400000000000001040
```

This is the little endian version of the WKB, so it looks slightly different than the big endian version shown in your example.